# Undeclared update indenifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, undeclared-identifier

```
#import "MainScene.h"
static const CGFloat scrollSpeed = 80.f;
@implementation MainScene {
    CCSprite *_hero;
    CCPhysicsNode *_physicsNode;
    CCNode *_ground1;
    CCNode *_ground2;
    NSArray *_grounds;
    NSTimeInterval _sinceTouch;


}

- (void)didLoadFromCCB {
    _grounds = @[_ground1, _ground2];
    self.userInteractionEnabled =TRUE;
}

- (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [_hero.physicsBody applyImpulse:ccp(0, 400.f)];


   // _sinceTouch+=delta;
    _hero.rotation = clampf(_hero.rotation, -30.f, 90.f);
    if (_hero.physicsBody.allowsRotation) {
        float angularVelocity = clampf(_hero.physicsBody.angularVelocity, -2.f, 1.f);
        _hero.physicsBody.angularVelocity = angularVelocity;
    }



//position of hero
- (void)update: (CCTime) delta {
    _hero.position = ccp(_hero.position.x + delta * scrollSpeed, _hero.position.y);
    _physicsNode.position = ccp(_physicsNode.position.x - (scrollSpeed *delta), _physicsNode.position.y);
// loop the ground
    for (CCNode *ground in _grounds) {

        // get the world position of the ground
        CGPoint groundWorldPosition = [_physicsNode convertToWorldSpace:ground.position];

        // get the screen position of the ground
        CGPoint groundScreenPosition = [self convertToNodeSpace:groundWorldPosition];

        // if the left corner is one complete width off the screen, move it to the right
        if (groundScreenPosition.x <= (-1 * ground.contentSize.width)) {
            ground.position = ccp(ground.position.x + 2 * ground.contentSize.width, ground.position.y);
            // clamp velocity
            float yVelocity = clampf(_hero.physicsBody.velocity.y, -1 * MAXFLOAT, 200.f);
            _hero.physicsBody.velocity = ccp(0, yVelocity);

            NSTimeInterval _sinceTouch;
            if ((_sinceTouch > 0.5f)) {
                [_hero.physicsBody applyAngularImpulse:-40000.f*delta];
            }

        }
        - (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
            [_hero.physicsBody applyImpulse:ccp(0, 400.f)];
            [_hero.physicsBody applyAngularImpulse:10000.f];
            _sinceTouch = 0.f;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

getting a undeclared identifier on "- (void)update: (CCTime) delta {" for update

I've tried for a while to resolve this  but can't seem to figure out how to declare the variable on that error any help will be greatly appreciated this is for a school project and it is due relitivly soon.

Thank you:)

Comment: Why are you using the `C++` tag? This is not C++ code.

Comment: You're missing a `}`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a closing "`}`" for this method:

```
- (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
```

It's unbalanced.

Comment: That fixed that error but added errors on " _hero.rotation = clampf(_hero.rotation, -30.f, 90.f);
    if (_hero.physicsBody.allowsRotation) { "     for undeclared iden and on " - (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
            [_hero.physicsBody applyImpulse:ccp(0, 400.f)];
            [_hero.physicsBody applyAngularImpulse:10000.f];
            _sinceTouch = 0.f;"  for undeclared iden on touchBegan

Comment: Also, get rid of the extra "`touchBegan`" declaration you've accidentally put within your `update`" function...